# Can you find the maximum vertex-degree $\Delta(H)$ of a graph $H$ given only the chromatic polynomial $P_H(k)$?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I'm working on an unassessed course problem,

> A graph $H$ has chromatic polynomial $$P_H(k)=k(k-1)(k-2)^3(k-3)^2(k^2-4k+6).$$ What is the chromatic number of $H$? Prove that the chromatic index of $H$ is at least $5$.

I see that $$P_H(0)=P_H(1)=P_H(2)=P_H(3)=0<P_H(4) \hspace{1em} \therefore \hspace{1em} \chi_H=4.$$ The only approach I can think of to show $5\leq\chi_H'$ is to show that $5\leq\Delta(H)$ and apply Vizing's Theorem, but I don't know how to do that given only this information. Could someone give me a pointer?

Comment: In general, you cannot find the maximum degree of a graph from its chromatic polynomial, because an $n$-vertex path (with maximum degree $2$) and an $n$-vertex star (with maximum degree $n-1$) both have chromatic polynomial $k(k-1)^{n-1}$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. Any suggestion on finding the chromatic index?

Comment: You can find the number of vertices and edges in the graph, which should be enough.